# how to check a user had selected nodes from two treeviews

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two treeviews in my windows application and there is a button..
The button should be only visible when the user selects nodes from both the treeviews.
How can this be done.
Please help me

Comment: Hi Gerald,I am not geting any errors.But i am confused and stuck in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both TreeViews look for the `AfterSelect` event. With the given event args (`TreeViewEventArgs`) you can find the node that is selected (or expended, etc.) with `e.Node`.
You could set the same event handler method for both Treeviews.

Then set your button visibility like `this.MyButton.Visible = (this.MyTreeView1.SelectedNode != null && this.MyTreeView2.SelectedNode != null);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AfterSelect event to check if both trees have nodes selected:

```
tree1.AfterSelect += new TreeViewEventHandler(tree_AfterSelect);
tree2.AfterSelect += new TreeViewEventHandler(tree_AfterSelect);

public void tree_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = tree1.SelectedNode != null && tree2.SelectedNode != null;
}
```